# JVM smart enought to optimize vararg array?

Tags: java, performance, jvm, variadic-functions, jit

Given we have a method like this and we want to be as fast and memory efficient as possible. Is it likely that JVM will be smart enought to optimize this into simple string builder appends and avoid creating Object[] for varargs and avoid autoboxing primitives into Object for that object array?

```
protected String stringId(Object... things) {
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (Object thing : things) {
        if(sb.length() > 0) {
            sb.append('-');
        }
        sb.append(String.valueOf(thing));
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Under the hood, the varagrs parameter _is_ an array; it's just syntactic sugar.

Comment: Varargs are syntactic sugar and always creates a new array. Since your paramter is an Object array there will be always autoboxing involved.

Comment: I don't know which JVMs, if any, will attempt that kind of optimization.  I don't _think_ it will, and even if it did, it would probably only happen if the call to this method was inlined.  Inlining depends on the callsite, and could easily vary across runs of the same program.

Comment: @Mike Strobel: indeed, especially as the array creation happens on the callsite as well. Without inlining, it’s impossible to conclude at the callsite that the array will be purely temporary.

Comment: Speaking of optimization, would it not also make sense to omit the `String.valueOf` to `StringBuilder.append`? The current implementation of `StringBuilder.append(Object obj)` (in Java 21) is just `append(String.valueOf(obj))`, so you would lose nothing by omitting the call yourself, gain brevity, and gain any performance improvements to `StringBuilder.append` in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The temporary array to hold the variable arguments is created at the *call site* and each call site will get optimized individually and may have the object allocation elided or not. It would require inlining of your method to the caller to allow the optimizer to prove that the array is purely temporary, i.e. does not escape.

However, whether this happens or not, is irrelevant. In an unoptimized execution scenario, you have a base footprint of at least five object instances, the array for the varargs, a `StringBuilder` and its backing array and the result `String` and its backing array. Then, for each argument that is not already a `String` or specially handled value (like `null` or a `boolean`), the invocation `String.valueOf(thing)` may return a new `String` instance, with a new backing array, before getting appended to the `StringBuilder`.

Also the `StringBuilder`’s backing array starts with a default capacity of 16 chars and will get replaced by a larger array each time the capacity is exhausted.

As said, that’s all for the unoptimized execution scenario and the optimizer will find a lot of optimization opportunities among these operations which have a much bigger impact than that sole array instance created for the varargs parameter. This also applies for values that needs to be auto-boxed. This auto-boxing happens at the caller as well and is subject to optimizations dedicated specifically to auto-boxing. For certain values, it is even mandatory to evaluate to the same object each time they get boxed.

Note that the often-overlooked real expenses are at different places. E.g., converting numerical values to their decimal representations is far more expensive than wrapping these values into a lightweight `Integer`, resp. `Double` object.